# Grep last N characters of each line in a file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep, tail

I have a file with millions of lines.And each line ends with a format say "XXX:some value" .. I want to grep only this word "XXX:some value" from each line and put it in a separate file.How can i achieve this using grep command?

PS: "some value" can be any string

Comment: Except for being an intellectual exercise, could you give a good reason why not to use perl or python for such a task? E.g. `perl -ne '/.*:(.*)$/ and print "$1\n"'`.

Comment: could you provide an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get last n characters of each line using `awk`:

```
cat file
asdf
asdfg
asdfgh
```

```
awk -vn=2 '{print substr($0,length($0)-n+1)}'
df
fg
gh
```

---

Or do you like to get data after  `XXX`, then do:

```
echo "here is my line XXX:22" | awk -F"XXX:" '{print $2}'
22
```

Comment: where is the file name in awk -vn=2 '{print substr($0,length($0)-n+1)}'?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-o` flag:

```
grep -o 'XXX:.*' <input >output
```

Comment: "Some value" can be any string.

Comment: @Karthik207 Good, because `.*` will match any string. Are you sure you're not confusing this response with the [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27645819/1600898)?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use grep as below:

```
grep -ow 'XXX:some value' myfile.txt > patternMatched.txt
```

Comment: I guess the `some value` could be any number/info, not just the text `some value`

Comment: I am not sure and tbh havent seen that in OP's post but if that's case OP could use regex as well. In anyways, i think above would work for exact match as per OP's input.

Comment: "Some value can be any string"

Comment: @Karthik207 that should still work.